# When i want a object to appear with an if statement, when i do its requirements it does not work. Swift, ARKit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, arkit

In my app, which uses ARKit I have a level, which is level 1, and at the bottom, there is a counter and everytime you press an addition sign, the counter goes up one. Once the counter gets to 20, I want the trophy to spawn, hence the "addTrophy()" function, but my "if" statement does nothing. How do I fix this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var points: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
@IBAction func congratsButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var congratulation: UIButton!
var counter:Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        points.text = "\(counter)"
    }
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    sceneView.session.run( configuration)
    func addObject4() {
     addObject()
     addObject()
     addObjectm()
     addObjectm()
     addObjectm()
     addObjectm()

}
    addObject4()

    let pointers = Int(self.points.text!)

    if pointers == 20 {
        points.textColor = UIColor.green
        addTrophy()
    } else {

    }

}
```

Comment: The question isn't understandable, nor is the problem, nor is the code

Answer (score 0):

Because `pointers` is set to 0. I can't understand what you are trying to achieve, and why you have an `if` statement if it equals 20.

Use `print` statements to debug your code.